# Rails accepts_nested_attributes > build being lost on validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

When a validation occurs whilst saving to the `location` model using `accepts_nested_attributes` for the location model, Rails will return the form blank when it previously held values.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sales
  validates_presence_of :street_address, :town, :state, :zip
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
  has_many :locations
end
```

When no validation error occurs, it will create the location absolutely fine, however when a validation error occurs on any part of the form, it seems the location fields' data is lost.

Any ideas?

**Controller code**

```
def new
    user = User.find(current_user.id)
    1.times { @sale.items.build; @sale.build_location; @sale.sale_times.build; }
  end

  def create
    @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @sale, status: :created, location: @sale }
      else
        format.html { 
          1.times { @sale.items.build; @sale.build_location;  }
          render action: "new" 
          }
        format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: having the exactly same issue... :(

Comment: It will be easy to solve if you post controller code.

Comment: @soundar have updated my post with the controller code

Comment: @Elliot you have used build_location but you have not declared has_one :location in Sale model

Comment: Did you have `form.fields_for :items, @sale.items.first do |item_fields|...` ?

Comment: @soundar the location model has_many :sales (just forgot to include that in this post - have updated)

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar question to the one here: [rails fields_for does not render after validation error on nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611543/rails-fields-for-does-not-render-after-validation-error-on-nested-form)

Look at the first answer and that should help

Comment: I thought rails is meant to retain nested_attributes on a validation error regardless?

Comment: Have updated with controller code. Believe that is already implemented?