# Rails - adding nested attributes then validation fails, new nested attributes are not passed back to the :edit render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a Rails app with nested attributes.  My MVC works great except when the nested validation fails.  Here is my parent model controller:

```
  def update

    if @model.update(model_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully updated.'}
      end

    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

The issue is then in my model view when I build the nested form again:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :nested_model, @model.nested_model.joins(:related_model).order(:name)  do |i| %>
```

I get all the original nested_model items in the form but the new ones that were passed in the params are not added.  This works 100% when there are no validation issues.  How do I add those invalid nested_model items back in here.  I feel like there is an existing solution to this that I can't seem to find easily.

**UPDATE**

Seems to be related to this:

[rails fields_for does not render after validation error on nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611543/rails-fields-for-does-not-render-after-validation-error-on-nested-form)

I need to add to my update and create actions:

```
@model.nested_model.build(params[:nested_model_attributes])
```

When I do some digging I can see that the newly created (but invalid records) are being passed to the view.  When the fields_for processes them if I remove the related object the form renders as expected:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :nested_model do |i| %>
```

except I want the join.  I am thinking I can work around that but it's ugly.  I tried:

```
@model.nested_model.joins(:related_model).build(params[:nested_model_attributes])
```

but that does not work.

Comment: You're chasing a red herring. `f.simple_fields_for :nested_model` will call `nested_model` on the object wrapped by the form. So if that object is `@model` there is absolutely no difference. Neither should you have explicitly pass anything. A more likely explanation is that you are rejecting the incoming parameters. Please add an actual minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: By rejecting I mean that you have passed the `reject_if` option to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. This does not validate, it just drops the hash.

Comment: Cleaned up my question a bit.  I am passing the object because I have a join and sort.  As mentioned the form works fine when the validation passes - all params are being passed.  I am not using `reject_if`.

Comment: I think I have this sorted out - I will clean up and answer that explains the issue and how I solved it.

Comment: You should not have to manually build anything if you are using nested attributes. Are you passing the right attribute and whitelisting it properly? That question is 10 years old so not a very good reference.

Comment: I and realizing that you are right.  The issue is actually now adding some logic for the new invalid nested records that are lacking the related association is.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at with the join which does not do anything since this is an insert/update query. If you want to insert data into the join table as well you need to use two levels of nested attributes. So you would do ‘A.create(b_attributes: { foo: 1, c_attributes: { bar: 2 }})‘